# How to call function onload in nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, facebook-pixel, nuxtjs2

I have an app in Nuxtjs 2. I'm using nuxt-facebook-pixel-module to track user activity on my websites. I add Facebook conversion API to it. I created an API endpoint which calls the Facebook conversion API, and now I want to call this endpoint every time I change the route and call the client-side function this.$fb.track(). This must also be the first time you launch the website and also on every route change. I don't want to add the same code to all my subpages because it would be a lot of redundant code. Is it possible to do this somehow through the plugins folder or through middleware?

I tried to make this through the plugins directory, but it works only from the first route change. When I open the website it doesn't work. Only when I refresh my page or go to other subpage.

That's how my plugins code look:

```
export default async ({ app }) => {
  app.router.afterEach(async (to, from) => {
    const eventId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000).toString()

    await fetch('/api/event-handle', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        data: [{some data}],
      }),
    })
    app.$fb.track('ViewContent', {}, eventId)
  })
}
```

and in my nuxt.config.js I add it like that:

```
 plugins: [
    { src: '@/plugins/facebook-client.js', mode: 'client' },
  ],
```

But when I run this code I see that in console the $fb function have been called like on the screenshot:
[image: console]

But in network tab I don't see any fetch request, only when i refresh page or go to other route.

[image: network tab]

If anyone can help me, I will be very grateful.

Comment: "subpage" - is it a nested route? Can you clarify which routes do you navigate?

Comment: I have pages folder with all of my routes. For example I have a blog directory where I have files like index.vue and _slug.vue for all my blog post. Of course, I have more folders for each subpage on my website. The home page, is in the main pages directory as an index.vue file. I want to enter code that calls the API and triggers the $fb event when visiting any of these pages.

Comment: Please, explain  the current behaviour. In which scenario does afterEach work and in which not? "but it works only from the first route change. When I open the website it doesn't work. Only when I refresh my page or go to other subpage" - this sounds contradictory. I'd expect it to be done the way you did in general

Comment: It's weird for me too. I've edited the post and I hope it will make it clearer what I mean. When a user enters my website, there is no API query, only the $fb function as shown in the screenshot. Then when I reload the page, the query is sent and everything works, but I want it to register immediately when the user enters the page, not after it is reloaded.

Comment: So $fb.track is called and fetch isn't? Does this mean that it's fetch that's the problem? The question isn't very clear on that. Regarding fetch, is it Nuxt's one? In this case it's expected to behave differently https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/components-glossary/fetch#the-fetch-hook

Comment: @EstusFlask Yeah $fb.track is called and fetch isn't. But I can't use fetch hook I think, becouse that's not the Nuxt component. It's the plugin directory https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/directory-structure/plugins

Comment: @EstusFlask I know what I was doing wrong. It was problem with my debugging tool. Everythink was working corectly at beggining but I check it in the wrong way. So thank you for your responses and your help.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with the requests here and why you can't see them in networks tab but here's no way how it could not be called, await fetch guarantees that. Probably that's "preserve log" checkbox

Comment: Glad you sorted this out